# Convert date from human readable format

Tags: datetime, go

I know that there is a [library](https://github.com/dustin/go-humanize) for doing opposite. I need to format string, for example, "a year ago" to any date format "29/02/15".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tricky because those libraries (like [`timeago`](https://github.com/xeonx/timeago)) would also translate time in "less than a minute ago" (which you cannot translate back into an exact time)

For exact expressions (like "3 months ago"), you need to use [`time.AddDate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate) (here `t.AddDate(0, -3, 0).Month()`)

Then you can format the resulting time into any date format you want with [`Time.Format`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#example_Time_Format) or [`metakeule/fmtdate`](https://github.com/metakeule/fmtdate).